# goroutine stack traces incomplete

Tags: performance, go

I wrote a web app using golang. When it's running in production, there are some goroutines blocked. Here are the information (generated by using `pprof`):

```
goroutine 792247 [chan receive, 948 minutes]:
database/sql.(*Tx).awaitDone(0xc4206e2b80)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1440 +0x57
created by database/sql.(*DB).begin
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1383 +0x274
```

The goroutine has been waiting on the channel for 948 minites. Apparently, there's something wrong. But the stack traces seems incomplete. It's not enough for me to find the bug. (I want some stack traces start from my program.)

How can I get the full stack traces of this goroutine?
Or are there any other ways to debug this issue?

**Update**:

I've read the source code of database/sql/sql.go. It turns out `database/sql/sql.go:1440` is in a new goroutine. The stack traces are `incomplete` because previous stack traces belong to the `parent` goroutine.

My question should be : are there better ways to debug this issue?

Comment: Try running `go run -race *.go`

Comment: @Acidic I've already tried that.  Maybe it's not some race condition. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Eagle [/database/sql/sql.go:1440](https://golang.org/src/database/sql/sql.go?#L1437) is waiting for a transaction to be committed or rolled back. You can check your code for transactions that are not resolved.

Comment: @JohnSPerayil I've checked my code. There are a lot of APIs which use SQL transaction. But I cannot find one without `Rollback` or `Commit`. That's why I want to get the full stack traces. Thanks anyway.

Comment: To be fair, the trace isn't incomplete. It's being called as `go tx.awaitDone()`. Each goroutine has its own stack, so that is the beginning on the stack for the goroutine you're examining.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, you're right. I've updated the question. Now I'm trying to modify some go source code to track the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to get the parent goroutine stack without you having to manually track each go routine invocation and generating an id for it.

In this specific case, what is likely is that you have a transaction that has not been Committed or Rollbacked because an error occurs and the function prematurely exits without calling either.

A good template to avoid the same is to use 'defer'.

```
func (s Service) DoSomething() (err error) {
    tx, err := s.db.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer func() {
        if err != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
            return
        }
        err = tx.Commit()
    }()
    if _, err = tx.Exec(...); err != nil {
        return
    }
    if _, err = tx.Exec(...); err != nil {
        return
    }
    // ...
    return }
```

[Code Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23502629/2285935)

PS: Beware of error shadowing.

Comment: Thanks. Using "defer" is far better. I just added `Rollback` or `Commit` before each `return`. However, I suppose it should achieve the same effect as your code.

Comment: @Eagle yes, defer produces cleaner code for the same functionality. I can't think of any other case for blocking goroutines in your case, will update the answer if I do.