# Do I need to explicitly rollback a transaction?

Tags: database, go

I would like to know how Go handles failed DB transaction. My code looks like:

```golang
func assert(e interface{}) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

//the caller will handle panics
func SomeDBOperation(db *sql.DB) {
    tx, err := db.Begin()
    assert(err)
    defer func() {
        if e := recover(); e != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
            panic(e)
        }
        assert(tx.Commit())
    }()
    // some code that can possibly panic...
}
```

Can I simplify the error checking like this:

```golang
func SomeDBOperation(db *sql.DB) {
    tx, err := db.Begin()
    assert(err)
    defer func() { assert(tx.Commit()) }()
    // some code that can possibly panic...
}
```

BTW, I am using SQLite, if any answer is db-specific, I would also like to know the behavior with MySQL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is important to rollback the tx if there is an error while executing any query, otherwise it is still running and holding locks. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896531/10984192) post .

Comment: I know this. What I am asking is actually a Go question, not DB question. i.e. I wonder if the `tx` will be rolled back on the exit of the function "automatically", if no commit is executed.  :-)

Comment: A non committed transaction gets rolled back automatically once the client disconnects or the transaction is garbage collected. More info https://stackoverflow.com/a/23502629/10984192 .

Answer (score 4):

By default, any *database* error will automatically cancel and rollback the transaction. That's what transactions are for.  So strictly speaking, in the case of a *database* error (i.e. foreign key violation or something), there's no need to rollback the transaction yourself.

However, you should always defer a rollback immediately after creating the transaction.  This is so that if there are any errors *not related to the database*, that the transaction is rolled back and cleaned up.  In such a case, rolling back a transaction that has already been aborted will be a no-op, so harmless.

The way this looks in code is something like this:

```golang
func SomeDBOperation(db *sql.DB) error {
    txn, err := db.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to start transaction: %w", err)
    }
    defer txn.Rollback() // nolint:errcheck
    /* ... whatever other logic and DB operations you care about */
    return nil
}
```